# Accessing Hotmail from Firefox: "XML Parsing Error: not well-formed"

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, xml

When I try to access my Hotmail account from my present computer I get the following error message:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://sn105w.snt105.mail.live.com/default.aspx 
Line Number 330, Column 51:
<img src="http://b.scorecardresearch.com/b?c1=2&c2=3000001&c3=&c4=wlhotm&c5=&c6=&c15=&cv=1.3&cj=1"
--------------------------------------------------^
```

I've tried clearing the cache, history, etc... and rebooting the computer.  I am running Ubuntu with Firefox 3.6.17.

I can access the account from other computers so it appears to be a problem with this machine and not the account.

Any ideas what this error might mean and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try Firefox in safe mode, http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode

If it works there, there's something in the profile - probably an addon that's conflicting with hotmail. http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Troubleshooting%20extensions%20and%20themes should get you back on track in that case.

That failing, the information from your about:support page might help us diagnose the problem.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions.  unfortunately safe-mode didn't help so I wound up just removing and reinstalling firefox.  That worked but is always somewhat unsatisfying.